# How to create a Map with generics Id and String?

Tags: apex, soql, map, generics

How to create a `Map<Id, String>([SELECT Id, Name from Account]);`?

The query returns `Map<Id, Account>`.

I want to get a `Map<Id, String>` without using loops and without having to iterate the query result.

Comment: You have to loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Adrian mentioned in his comment, you cannot do this without a loop.

The Map constructor that takes a `List<SObject>` (which is what SOQL queries normally return unless you're including something like `GROUP BY`) will always result in a `Map<Id, SObject>`.